# I want to write a script that searches all directories in $PATH with the find or ls command

Tags: bash, path, find

total newbie here.  I would like to write a bash script that will allow me to perform a find or ls command on all of the directories in $PATH.  I would need it to take a search string, and run either find or ls (I don't know which is better) on all of the directories that are returned from $PATH.  Thanks!

What I have so far:

```
arr=$(echo $PATH | tr ":" "\n")

echo -n "SEARCH STRING:"
read STRING

for x in $arr
do
    find /"$x" -iname "$STRING"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out my solution for that here: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/blog/konsolebox-210384/binfind-search-for-executable-files-based-from-path-variable-35012/